# background thread running in intervals

Tags: .net, web-applications

I'm running a .net web application and need to read data from xml files and put the data into cache. I need to check the files every five minutes. I'm considering what is best option. Should I start a thread in global.asax or create a HttpModule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, read this http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

After that I really recommend trying out Haackeds WebBackgrounder which can be found at https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder

Comment: I'll try it out, it seems like a good and safe approach, thnx

Answer (score 1):

Creating long running threads inside web application is not a good idea.
Quite simple and effective aproach is to make a page, that will act as a entrypoint for your data reading code. Then simply add `wget http://localhost/yourpage` to the Task Scheduler with appropriate interval. wget will load your page and start import process.